# Pronunciation of "privacy" in Canadian English

Tags: pronunciation, canadian-english

Do Canadians follow the American English pronunciation with the "eye" phoneme or do they tend to stick with the Commonwealth pronunciation, i.e. with the short "i" vowel?

(Sorry, don't seem to be able to paste IPA.)

Comment: The OED gives both versions in the UK, with /aɪ/ in the US. It does not mention Canada.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there is a 'Commonwealth pronunciation' in this case. It's rare for Australians to use the short 'i' for example. Canadians too as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Justin Trudeau uses the American pronunciation; see around 06:40 in [this video.](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=0uX2pHobOzI&pp=ygUWSnVzdGluIHRydWRlYXUgcHJpdmFjeQ%3D%3D)

Comment: This is anecdotal evidence (based on a single example), so probably better for a comment than an answer.